# Is there any method to share database in iphone?

Tags: iphone, database

I want build a app, in that app i should  able to shear my database with every one.
Is there any method to do that?

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific. Do you mean share your database with other apps on the iPhone, or with other iPhones? Or do you mean have one central database that your iPhone app will connect to?

Comment: yes i mean one central database that your iphone app will connect

Answer (score 1):

Not in Apple's security model.  You can share it between several of your own applications, if your set things up correctly to begin with.